# Difference between projection multiple fields and use $and operation

Tags: mongodb

How difference between

```
db.collection.find({ field1: <value>, field2: <value> })
```

and

```
db.collection.find({ $and: [{field1: <value>}, {field2: <value>}] })
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference. From the documentation:

> MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma
>   separated list of expressions. Using an explicit AND with the $and
>   operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be
>   specified in multiple expressions.

Hope my answer was helpful.